# How can i recover MKV file after OBS Crash?

Tags: video, matroska

I have 7.78 GB 2 hours long video file. I can play it but when i try to seek player crashing. I record it with OBS as a screen capture. My screen flashed and game crashed after that i checked obs and clicked "stop recording". Nothing happened OBS couldn't finish it. I wait 10 mins and kill it from process. Is there any way to repair this mkv ? "Stellar Repair For Video" couldn't repait it. Thanks! (Sorry for my english)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just extract video and all audio tracks with ffmpeg. It's worked for me.

You can find more info in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922226/extract-every-audio-and-subtitles-from-a-video-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Please [edit] this answer and add enough detail to make it useful to other people.